# All elements of a set

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

I am trying to solve the following problem;

Write all elements of the following set: $ A=\left \{ x\in\mathbb{R}; \sqrt{8-t+\sqrt{2-t}}\in\mathbb{R}, t\in\mathbb{R} \right \}$ .

My assumption is that the solution is $\mathbb{R}$ and we don't need to solve when are the square roots defined, because of the $x$. Am I correct?

Thanks

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA Only the fact that $A$ is either empty or whole $\mathbb{R}$ follows from your reasoning.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy The condition is written in terms of $x$, it just depends on $x$ trivially. $f(x)=1$ is a well-defined function of $x$

Comment: It is wrong  to say that $\sqrt {8-t+\sqrt {2-t}} \in \mathbb R$ for all $t \in mathbb R$ because the exprestion is  not defined when $t>2$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Yes, this means that the condition is trivially false, so no $x$ satisfies the condition, so the resulting set is empty (absolutely correctly defined, but empty). We need to define set-constructor notation for such trivial cases for things like $\{x| f(x),\ \phi(x)\}=\{x| f(x)\}\cap \{x|\phi(x)\}$ to hold.

Comment: @Serg - probably you are right, provided that we read the expression in the def of the set as the formula $\forall t (t \in \mathbb R \to \sqrt \ldots \in \mathbb R)$ (that IMO is a very sloppy way of writing a formula ...).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Yes, I also think this is sloppy. I think that there should at least be the $\forall$ quantifier before $t\in\mathbb{R}$, and even then one could argue that the condition is not false but undefined.

Comment: Does "$\sqrt{8-t+\sqrt{2-t}}\in\mathbb{R}, t\in\mathbb{R}$" mean "$\sqrt{8-t+\sqrt{2-t}}\in\mathbb{R}$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$", or does it mean "$\sqrt{8-t+\sqrt{2-t}}\in\mathbb{R}$ for some $t\in\mathbb{R}$", or does it mean "$\sqrt{8-t+\sqrt{2-t}}\in\mathbb{R}$ and $t\in\mathbb{R}$"? In the third case $t$ is a free variable, so the set $A$ will depend on $t$.

Answer (score 1):

I believe all the other answers misinterpret the question. The answer $A=[\sqrt{6},+\infty)$ would be correct if it was phrased as $A=\{x\in\mathbb{R}| x=\sqrt{8-t+\sqrt{2-t}}, t\in\mathbb{R}\}$. I am interpreting the question as "What is $A=\{x\in\mathbb{R}| \sqrt{8-t+\sqrt{2-t}}\in\mathbb{R}\quad \forall t\in\mathbb{R}\}$". Notice the quantifier at the end, which is often omitted in such cases.

I think the answer is the empty set. I think that the point of the problem is to teach you that things like $A=\{x\in B| 0=1\}$ construct an empty set. Your $A$ consists of $x$ such that for all $t$ $\sqrt{8-t+\sqrt{2-t}}$ is well-defined. Since it is always undefined for $t>2$ (or, even better, defined as a complex number with positive imaginary part), no $x$ satisfies this condition and $A$ turns out to be empty.

Basically, when you have a set defined as $A=\{x\in B| \phi\}$, where $\phi$ is some statement not dependent on $x$, then $A=B$ ($\phi$ is True), or $A=\varnothing$.

Answer (score 0):

The set $A$ is not properly defined. I am interpreting $A$ as the range of $\sqrt {8-t+\sqrt {2-t}}$.

$\sqrt {8-t+\sqrt {2-t}}$ is defined only when $t \leq 2$. This function is continuous and decreasing. It tends to $\infty$ as $ x \to -\infty$ and the value at $x=2$ is $\sqrt 6$. Hence the answer is $[\sqrt 6,\infty)$.

Comment: not sure I follow. How can it be defined when t ≤ 2? Didn't you mean undefined?

Comment: $2-t \geq 0$ is equivalent to $t \leq 2$.